# Spring batch deployed on openshift using several pods

Tags: openshift, spring-batch

I deploy an application on Openshift and I use at least 2 pods.

My war contains a Spring Batch application, scheduled by a Spring cron.

Of course, each pod start the same batch at the same time, and it's my problem/question.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour ? I would like to start only one batch instance (or is there a way to configure Spring batch to check if a batch is already running ?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Deployment, it's not trivial, but here are some ideas that can help you.

1. Use ScheduledJobs/CronJobs from Kubernetes. Meaning you would ditch controling of launching batch from your app completely and have dedicated pod launched to perform batch job and die
2. Use master elector sidecar for establishing the right to exec batch (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/election)
3. Implement some locking mechanism on your own
4. Use StatefulSet and bind batch to run only on a praticular hostname (ie. by config var passed to Pods like BATCH_HOSTNAME. StatefulSets have deterministic names so you could say that batch should run only on `my-pods-0`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need leader election in your situation.  Spring Integration provides leader election functionality you can use to determine who is the master.  That master would be the one that actually launches the jobs.  The other would just ignore the scheduled event.  You can read more about Spring Integration's leader election in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/support/leader/LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.html